# ASP.Net & SQL SERVER

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, entity-framework

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос. Я пишу приложение чат на asp.net api. Я хочу чтобы сообщения сохранялись в sql server. Для этого я в sql server создал таблицу user c полями id, name, message. В visual studio подключил эту таблицу. 
Как сделать так чтобы сообщения хранились в sql server?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ответ на данный вопрос можно найти в документации к ASP.Net и его легко найти в Google или другой поисковой системе.

Comment: Возможно TC просто не знает куда "рыть", т.к. не совсем понятно в вопросе, что значит "В visual studio подключил эту таблицу"

Comment: модель ado.net edm

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас уже есть модель (контекст EF), и есть конкретное место, где нужно сохранять сообщение (экшн на сервере), то код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    context.Users.Add(new User { Name = data.Name, Message = data.Message };
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

где `data` - пришедший в эшкн объект с именем пользователя и сообщением.